# select drop down jquery, through applescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, applescript

Ok I have been going at this for some time and it is time to ask.
Hours of searching has got me nowhere.

I am using applescript and do java to: 
√-Load page
√-delay
√-auto fill text fields
X-select option from a drop down
...
more to add but stuck here
...

```
tell application "Safari"
activate

set VAR to "foo"
tell (make new document) to set URL to "site.exam.pl"
delay 2

do JavaScript "document.forms[1]['edit-title'].value = '" & VAR & "'" in document 1


do JavaScript "document.forms[1]['field_original[und][0][value]'].value = '" & VAR & "'" in document 1
(* Group *)

do JavaScript "$('#edit-field').val('2').change();" in current tab of window 1
```

end tell
Taken from the site: (slightly modified)

```
<select id="edit-field" name="field_group[foo]" class="form-select required">
<option value="_none">- Select a value -</option>
<option value="3">foo3</option>
<option value="0">foo0</option>
<option value="4">Foo4</option>
<option value="1">foo1</option>
<option value="2">foo2</option>
```

```
$('#edit-field').val('2').change();
```

works fine on http://jsfiddle.net

But I can not get it to work on the site through this script.
I have also tried:

```
--do JavaScript document.forms[1][field_group[foo]].value = 2
--do JavaScript document.getElementById  
--do JavaScript "document.getElementById ('field_group[foo]').selectedIndex" = 4
--do JavaScript "document.edit-field-group.xxform-select.required.selectedIndex" = 4
--do JavaScript "document.forms['edit-field-group']['field_group[foo]'].option.value = '2'" in front document
--do JavaScript " $('select#'edit-field-group' option:nth-child(1)');" in current tab of window 1
--do JavaScript " $('select#'edit-field-group' option:eq(2)');" in current tab of window 1
--do JavaScript " $('select#edit-field-group option:eq(3)').attr('selected', true);" in current tab of window 1
```

But I can't get it to work on the site itself. 
Anyideas?

Comment: If anyone reading this has a good reference for AppleScript do JavaScript and/or JQuery, that would be extremely helpful! There seems to be so many ways to do any one thing in JS, but can't find any listing and syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('edit-field').value = '1'" in document 1
end tell
```

Comment: OMG, this was driving me mad! Thank you very much. Apparently I need to brush up on my JS.